# How do I set and get custom database variables?

Tags: postgresql

Using `PGAdmin III` I can right-click on a database, navigate to the `Variables` tab, and put a variable name-value property on the database itself.  Is there a way to customize these?  I saw an `application_name` variable, but I'd like to have an `application_version` variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to @dezso's answer, these variables can be changed with

```
SELECT set_config('class.name', 'value', valid_for_transaction_only::boolean)
```

and read with

```
SELECT current_setting('class.name')
```

See this link for more info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-admin.html

Answer (score 8):

You have to add the variable to the end of your `postgresql.conf` like

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

custom_variable_classes = 'general'     # list of custom variable class names

general.application_version = 'v1.0'
```

When restarted, you can add `general.application_version` manually in PgAdmin (it will not show up in the drop-down - at least not for me).  Otherwise, you can use it just like any other PostgreSQL variable.

## Update for version 9.2 and newer

From PostgreSQL 9.2 onwards, we don't have to set `custom_variable_classes` anymore.  One can set whatever variable they want - the only limitation seems to be it still has to have two parts:

```
SET something TO 'bla';
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "something"

SET thing.something TO 'bla';
SET
```

I guess this is so to avoid collision with the builtin parameters.

Comment: Hmmm. No way to do that from a SQL query in the database?

Comment: You have to first define the variables in postgresql.conf.  AFAIK this requires restarting PostgreSQL, so you can't do that from SQL.